# I am trying to make a .bat installer to install more .bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, installation

I am trying to make a few programs in batch that can be installed onto a flash drive or hard drive. I am using > and >> to make a new file called test.bat and adding lines to it. When the program is done a new batch file will be made that can run. I've encounter a problem. The batch file I am trying to install also uses > and >>. This causes some of my line to look like this. 'ECHO ECHO HI>"E:\Log.txt">"E:\Program.bat"' When run it doesn't copy part of my line. I am trying to find a way to install multiple batch files with just one.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: ...and post your scripts, or parts of them so we can see what you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the first redirection symble (>) with a caret (^):

`ECHO ECHO HI ^> "E:\Log.txt" > "E:\Program.bat"`

Found this at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php by Googling "how to escape characters in dos batch"